# Why can't I enter in the value column for Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

This might be the dumbest question ever but why can't I enter anything into the value column in Selenium IDE whenever I manually enter something into the target column.

Here's what I want to go:
storeAttribute | //html/body/div/div[2]/p/em/a/@href | insertvalue

but Selenium IDE is not letting me enter things into the value column "insertvalue".

Answer (score 1):

give command such as

command:type

target: //html/body/div/div[2]/p/em/a/@href

value:insertvalue

Comment: I still can't access the value column. I don't understand why. The value column is basically unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Selenium IDE as a sidebar in the Firfox (30) browser widow?
Value field is disabled when the IDE is used in the sidebar. It could be a bug.

It work fine when selenium IDE (2.5.0)  is opened as a separate window.

What are the  IDE and Firefox versions in your environment?